# 2 ROWS FOR AN ITEM IN SQL QUERY RESULTS WHEN EXPECTING 1 ROW

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query all ACTIVE rows in table A but if in Table B, there is an ACTIVE row for column ITEM where the TRACKING_FL is Y and the LOCATION is MAIN, then I want the value of the tracking_fl, cost, and location from Table B.  There should only be one row in the results per item.

If the values for a row in Table B are not present, then there should be a one row with values from Table A.

The problem is if the criteria pertaining to Table B is true then I get two rows in the results, one with the values from Table B and one from Table A.

Current vs Desired results are outlined below.  Create Table and Insert statements for sample data is outlined below.  Thank you in advance for assistance!

CURRENT CODE:

```
SELECT 
    A.ITEM, 
    A.DESCRIPTION, 
    CASE WHEN B.LOCATION='MAIN' AND B.ACTIVE_STATUS='A' AND B.TRACKING_FL='Y' THEN B.TRACKING_FL ELSE 'N' END AS TRACKING_FL,
    CASE WHEN B.LOCATION='MAIN' AND B.ACTIVE_STATUS='A' AND B.TRACKING_FL='Y' THEN B.COST ELSE A.PRICE END  AS AMOUNT,
    CASE WHEN B.LOCATION='MAIN' AND B.ACTIVE_STATUS='A' AND B.TRACKING_FL='Y' THEN B.LOCATION  ELSE A.VENDOR END  AS SOURCED
FROM 
    TABLE A A
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM
WHERE 
    A.ACTIVE_STATUS= 'A'
```

CURRENT RESULT:

| ITEM | DESCRIPTION | TRACKING_FL | AMOUNT | SOURCED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO948 | LABEL IV 1X3 CHANGE ON WED | N | 92.5 | ACME |
| SO948 | LABEL IV 1X3 CHANGE ON WED | Y | 6.75 | MAIN |
| SO944 | LABEL FOR HANDHELD IN LAB ONLY | N | 350.2 | ACME |
| SO944 | LABEL FOR HANDHELD IN LAB ONLY | Y | 8.23 | MAIN |
| SO910 | HEADSET W/6 FT CORD | N | 25.99 | CDW |
| 29965 | HCG CC 5 ELECSYS | N | 35.39 | ACME |

EXPECTED RESULT:

| ITEM | DESCRIPTION | TRACKING_FL | AMOUNT | SOURCED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO948 | LABEL IV 1X3 CHANGE ON WED | Y | 6.75 | MAIN |
| SO944 | LABEL FOR HANDHELD IN LAB ONLY | Y | 8.23 | MAIN |
| SO910 | HEADSET W/6 FT CORD | N | 25.99 | CDW |
| 29965 | HCG CC 5 ELECSYS | N | 35.39 | ACME |

CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
ITEM    CHAR(32 BYTE)   No      1,  
DESCRIPTION CHAR(30 BYTE)   No      2,  
VENDOR  CHAR(35 BYTE)   No      3,
PRICE   NUMBER(10,0)    No      4,
ACTIVE_STATUS   CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      5
);

INSERT INTO TABLE A
(ITEM, DESCRIPTION, VENDOR, PRICE, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('SO948','LABEL IV 1X3 CHANGE ON WED','ACME',92.5,'A')

INSERT INTO TABLE A
(ITEM, DESCRIPTION, VENDOR, PRICE, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('SO944','LABEL FOR HANDHELD IN LAB ONLY','ACME',350.2,'A')

INSERT INTO TABLE A
(ITEM, DESCRIPTION, VENDOR, PRICE, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('SO910', 'HEADSET W/6 FT CORD', 'CDW',25.99,'A')

INSERT INTO TABLE A
(ITEM, DESCRIPTION, VENDOR, PRICE, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('29965', 'HCG CC 5 ELECSYS','ACME', 35.39, 'A')

INSERT INTO TABLE A
(ITEM, DESCRIPTION, VENDOR, PRICE, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('12346', 'HGLOVE SM EXAM', 'ACME', 19.99, 'I')



CREATE TABLE B (
ITEM    CHAR(32 BYTE)   No      1,  
TRACKING_FL CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      2,  
COST    NUMBER(10,0)    No      3,    
LOCATION    CHAR(5 BYTE)    No      4,
ACTIVE_STATUS   CHAR(1 BYTE)    No      5
);

INSERT INTO TABLE B
(ITEM, TRACKING_FL, COST, LOCATION, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('SO948'    ,'Y',6.75,'MAIN','A');

INSERT INTO TABLE B
(ITEM, TRACKING_FL, COST, LOCATION, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('SO944'    ,'Y',8.23,'MAIN','A');

INSERT INTO TABLE B
(ITEM, TRACKING_FL, COST, LOCATION, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('MS1234'    ,'N',2.25,'MAIN','A');

INSERT INTO TABLE B
(ITEM, TRACKING_FL, COST, LOCATION, ACTIVE_STATUS)
VALUES
('MS5398'    ,'Y',9.10,'MAIN','I');
```

Sample table data:

**TABLE A**

| ITEM | DESCRIPTION | VENDOR | PRICE | ACTIVE_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO948 | LABEL IV 1X3 CHANGE ON WED | ACME | 92.5 | A |
| SO944 | LABEL FOR HANDHELD IN LAB ONLY | ACME | 350.2 | A |
| SO910 | HEADSET W/6 FT CORD | CDW | 25.99 | A |
| 29965 | HCG CC 5 ELECSYS | ACME | 35.39 | A |
| 12346 | HGLOVE SM EXAM | ACME | 19.99 | I |

TABLE B

| ITEM | TRACKING_FL | COST | LOCATION | ACTIVE_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO948 | Y | 6.75 | MAIN | A |
| SO944 | Y | 8.23 | MAIN | A |
| MS1234 | N | 2.25 | MAIN | A |
| MS5398 | Y | 9.10 | MAIN | I |

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, despite the sample data you shared with us, that each `ITEM` in `TableA` has two records in `TableB`. Working from that assumption, then I believe you want to put your `TableB` filters in the ON clause of your `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Otherwise you will be pulling `TableB` records that match on the same `ITEM` but don't fit your criteria. Then you can change from a case expression to a `COALESCE()`

```
SELECT A.ITEM, 
  A.DESCRIPTION, 
  COALESCE(B.TRACKING_FL,'N') AS TRACKING_FL,
  COALESCE(B.COST,A.PRICE)  AS AMOUNT,
  COALESCE(B.LOCATION, A.VENDOR)  AS SOURCED
FROM TABLE A A
  LEFT JOIN TABLE B
    ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM
    AND B.LOCATION='MAIN' AND B.ACTIVE_STATUS='A' AND B.TRACKING_FL='Y'
WHERE A.ACTIVE_STATUS= 'A'
```

Comment: Table  B would  only have the item 1 time if it exists at all.  just updated the post to include sample data for table A and table B.

Comment: If TableA has distinct ITEMs (no duplicates) and TableB has distinct ITEMs (no duplicates) then there is no mechanism via a LEFT OUTER JOIN where ITEM could become duplicate. Furthermore, if I put your sample data into a database and run your sql, I will not get duplicates. So my question to you is: where are your duplicates coming from? I still suspect that TableB has two records for Item `S0948` (as an example). One record matches your filter `B.LOCATION='MAIN' AND B.ACTIVE_STATUS='A' AND B.TRACKING_FL='Y` and the other does not.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=561726c483821c1b747ca4fd8335cd90)

Comment: @JNevill To your question of where are dups coming from, if you look at the current result item SO948 has 2 rows (1) tracking fl N with source ACME and (2)tracking fl Y with source MAIN.  I'm looking for the result #2 where if SO948 exists in table B with tracking fl Y for the MAIN location. I don't want the #1 row

Comment: @JNevill....adding on from my last comment above, The Expected Result table has exactly what I'm seeking.